# The column name specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument

Tags: sql-server

I my SQL Server stored procedure I have following pivot:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT
         CustomerProvince,
         SalesCount,
         InstallationCount,
         Brand,
         Brand AS Brandt
     FROM 
         #salehi1) StudentResults
PIVOT 
    (SUM(SalesCount)
        FOR Brand IN ([XVISION], [TCL])
    ) AS PivotTable
PIVOT 
    (SUM(InstallationCount)
        FOR Brandt IN ([XVISION], [TCL])
    ) AS PivotTable1
```

When I execute this query, I get an error but I must only use [XVISION] and [TCL] in this query:

> The column name "XVISION" specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument
>
> The column name "TCL" specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument

How can I solve the problem. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: How do you expect to differentiate between two columns named `XVISION` and two other columns named `TCL` in the code that consumes the results of the pivot query? Have you considered naming the `brandt` values differently than their original values so that they have different column names?

Comment: looks like you are trying to preform pivoting on 2 columns. For such case It is easier to use conditional aggregate like `SUM(CASE WHEN Brand = 'XVISION' THEN SalesCount END) AS XVISIONSalesCount, SUM(CASE WHEN Brand = 'XVISION' THEN InstallationCount END) AS XVISIONInstallationCount` rather than using `pivot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code, you would end up with two sets of identical columns.

It looks like you are just trying to pivot two columns into four. It's easier to do this with conditional aggregation.

```sql
SELECT
  CustomerProvince,
  XVISION_SalesCount = SUM(CASE WHEN Brand = 'XVISION' THEN SalesCount END),
  TCL_SalesCount     = SUM(CASE WHEN Brand = 'TCL'     THEN SalesCount END),
  XVISION_InstallationCount = SUM(CASE WHEN Brand = 'XVISION' THEN InstallationCount END),
  TCL_InstallationCount     = SUM(CASE WHEN Brand = 'TCL'     THEN InstallationCount END)
FROM 
    #salehi1 StudentResults
GROUP BY
  CustomerProvince;
```